# Не запускается mvn compile, mvn install

Tags: java, maven, cmd, компиляция

Пробую собрать проект с помощью Maven, уже много источников прочла, не могу понять в чем проблема. Каждый раз, после ввода в консоль mvn verify, mvn compile, mvn install вижу следующий результат:

```
    C:\Users\1>mvn -version
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 
    Maven home: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.9
    Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre


    C:\Users\1>mvn verify
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.113 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-09T20:22:41+03:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/77M
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
    [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there
    is no POM  in this directory (C:\Users\1). Please verify you
    invoked Maven from the  correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
     the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
    please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1]    
    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: but there is no POM  in this directory (C:\Users\1)

Comment: Файл pom.xml. В директории C:\Users\1 его нет. Значит, собирать нечего.

Comment: спасибо, pom у меня действительно в другой директории

Answer (score 0):

> but there is no POM  in this directory (C:\Users\1)
>   у тебя **отсутствует** файл **pom.xml** в директории, откуда запускается package (C:\Users\1). Ищи там, где скачивал дистр.